# Rails app , blogit integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails, I've a rails app and I'm trying to integrate a blog engine - blogit,
but when I run the app, I get `undefined local variable or method - root_path` ,
also, my app layout is trying to render for that blogit engine, 
help me solve this issue,

`localhost:3000/blog/posts` - `undefined local variable or method - root_path`
`localhost:3000/blog/posts/index` - `no route matches blog/post/index`

is it not mounted properly? i've just folowed the steps mentioned in the git https://github.com/KatanaCode/blogit

Comment: can you show the routes file ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need add `root to`:

```
root to: "posts#index", as: :blog_root
```

instead of `get "/" => "posts#index", as: :blog_root`